# FullCalendar: "Uncaught SyntaxError: Unexpected token :"

Tags: javascript, html, fullcalendar

Estou com uma dor de cabeça danada. Meu full calendar estava funcionando perfeitamente, todavia ele parou de funcionar. Ele acusa o seguinte erro:
"Uncaught SyntaxError: Unexpected token :".

Segue abaixo o cenário:

```html
<!-- fullcalendar css -->
<link href="{{asset('admin/assets/plugins/fullcalendar/fullcalendar.min.css')}}" rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" />
<!-- fullcalendar print css -->
<link href="{{asset('admin/assets/plugins/fullcalendar/fullcalendar.print.min.css')}}" rel="stylesheet" media='print' type="text/css" />

<script src="{{asset('admin/assets/plugins/fullcalendar/lib/moment.min.js')}}" type="text/javascript"></script>
<script src="{{asset('admin/assets/plugins/fullcalendar/fullcalendar.min.js')}}" type="text/javascript"></script>
```

Parte do fullcalendar:

```js
     var calender = $('#calendar');
        $(calender).fullCalendar({
            header: {
                left: 'prev,next today',
                center: 'title',
                right: 'month,agendaWeek,agendaDay,listMonth',
            },
            defaultDate: Date('Y-m-d'),
            navLinks: true, // can click day/week names to navigate views
            businessHours: true, // display business hours
            editable: true,
            droppable: true, // this allows things to be dropped onto the calendar
            lang: 'pt-br',
            drop: function() {
                // is the "remove after drop" checkbox checked?
                if ($('#drop-remove').is(':checked')) {
                    // if so, remove the element from the "Draggable Events" list
                    $(this).remove();
                }
            },
            events: [
                @foreach($causas as $causa)

                    {

                        title: "{{$causa->acao->acao ?? '' }}",
                        start: "{{$causa->prazo ?? '' }}",
                        end:"{{$causa->prazo ?? '' }}",
                        url: "{{route('admin.causas.perfil',['id' => $causa->id]) ?? ''}}",
                        color: "{{$causa->color}} !important",
                        textColor: "#FFFFFF"

                    }, 
                    @endforeach

            ]
        });
    }
```

O calendar simplesmente não esta sendo impresso na tela... Ja fiz a conferencia nas controladoras e os dados estao sendo enviados para  view...Alguem sabe o que pode ser, estava a funcionar normalmente...

Comment: Acho que queres esse `events` como objeto e não como array certo? ou seja `events: {...}` em vez de `events: [...]`...

Comment: Editei a pergunta, havia me expressado mal e com poucos detalhes

Comment: parece meio simples mas, isso pode dar erro: `right: 'month,agendaWeek,agendaDay,listMonth',`, já tentou remover a vírgula no final?

Comment: Dentro de Events eu substitui o ?? ' ' por ?? ' sem acao '. Voltou a funcionar, mas esta a me incomodar muito isso pois honestamente não entendi o motivo